# Job offer without face-to-face meeting

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-offer

I recently got a .NET Developer Trainee position after 3 phone interviews.

1. HR
2. First technical interview (Skype)
3. Second Technical interview

At no point was a face-to-face(onsite) interview suggest, no references were asked, nothing, but a job offer was presented, lower bounds of a junior .NET developer, so no such thing as "too good to be true" kind of offer.

I have done a bit of research into the company for a few days, and nothing suspicious about them online, so far. No bad reviews, no disgruntled ex-employee or blacklisting anywhere.

This is my first "real" job and I'm not just sure what to make of all these.

Is this considered a norm, if it happens at all? For a trainee position?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that, there is a 6 weeks **on-site** training phase, offer **does not** depend on this training.

Deadline for accepting/declining offer **April 7**

Training starts on **May 15**

---

### Update:

I decided not to proceed with this offer after seeking further clarifications on the *offer* letter itself:

*Offer letter was not signed by you or whoever prepared it.*

> This is not the official offer letter yet, we will give you the official offer letter after the one week orientation evaluation  with the company signature

*The job offer sounds great but it is somewhat confusing. I am asking because, the salary of $X0,000.00 per annum - is that uninterrupted, meaning is this a paid position whether I am sent on assignment or not? Or is the salary dependent on having an assignment with a client? Which means that if there are gaps between client assignments that I am sent on, "am I still paid the per annum salary through Company?"*

> If there are gaps between your project, then we will pay you stipend (2.5% of $X0,000.00/month), but we will try to make sure there's no gap between your projects

---

There was no need for me to schedule a visit to the company itself.

Comment: Do they have an office address? Have you checked it's there?

Comment: Yes, they have an office address, though, I have not verified it physically. The only verification I have done so far is to type the address into Google search, ALL results seem to match the company name and address.

Comment: Do you have a WRITTEN offer?

Comment: @codenoir  Yes, I do. The news was first conveyed over the phone, then I asked for a written offer and it was sent. Everything that was stated over the phone was included in the offer letter. They also gave a two weeks grace period to review the offer and accept, if I wish.

Comment: @hello - why won't you offer them to drop by to sort out all the paperwork and at the same time have a look at the premises and perhaps make acquaintance with the team you'll be working with? I assume the company is not at the other end of the world for you.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: They will probably turn over junior staff pretty quickly. Most likely the basically throw juniors against the wall and see who sticks.

Comment: @Snowlockk What does "see who sticks" mean in this regard?

Comment: Are you paid during the training?

Comment: Yes, I'm paid.. That was also included in the written offer I got.

Comment: They try out lots of people and see who can do the work to the level they want then they find a way to get rid of those that don't make the grade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work in recruitment, and have placed individuals in the manner you describe - usually for home office based roles however.

I would proceed with caution for the following reasons:

- No experience of company culture (what are the people like, atmosphere, etc.)
- No idea of what the offices are like (facilities, food, parking, desk arrangements)

These may seem like minor points, but these are things that **will** impact you day-to-day.

I would strongly suggest that you ask them for an office visit **before** signing anything.

Happy to elaborate as needed

EDIT: The placements I mentioned were for Enterprise level companies, so no F2F interview does not suggest any foul play.  It is important however that you make a fully informed decision - no one wants to be miserable every day for the sake of a simple office visit.

Comment: Additional reasons for an office visit: It will help to clarify if the company is trying to hire for a remote position (ie: do they even have room for you in the office?  Is working remotely a problem for you as an employee?)  It will also give you a sense of the daily commute, and how easy or difficult that will be for you.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: @hello Does the training take place before you need to sign?  If not, I would still absolutely request a site visit beforehand.  It only needs to be an informal email - it will be worth the peace of mind.

Comment: No, after. Deadline for accepting/declining is April 7, training starts on May 15,

Comment: Ultimately it is about what feels right to you.  However, in my experience I would still ask - it is not going to count against you in any way.  It may in face underline your enthusiasm for the role.

Answer (score 6):

If I were in your position, with two weeks to make a decision, I would take the initiative to schedule an appointment to go visit the site before accepting the offer.  I don't know if you have any other opportunities in the works but you will kick yourself if you turn those down and show up on your new job and quickly discover that the work environment is unacceptable or the place is a s--thole. Go meet the team! Feel people out. You've got to see these people every day, right?  Do your due diligence, and don't commit to a mess.

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 3):

I have been doing IT Consulting for over 25 years.  It is my experience that in the vast majority of cases companies that are willing to hire on phone interviews alone are what I call "Meat Grinders."  The idea is that your average recruit will be able to produce alot more than they cost to employ.  Sure you get some bad apples but many times the company can even make a profit on these.

Meat Grinder companies tend to have a high rate of turnover at all staff levels, but especially management.  These companies offer below market rate compensation, but often with some almost too good to believe perks after a certain extended amount of time.  The key there is that very few last long enough to qualify for those perks.  These companies usually pay on salary, and insist on working lots of over time, have unrealistic timelines and expectations.

That said these companies are great for someone new who needs to get some experience under their belt, or people who are having difficulty finding a position.  It is much easier to get a new job if you already have a job and can show your reliability and ability to produce. So go into this position with a positive attitude and open eyes.  Prove yourself and get the training, then in a year or so find a new company that will treat you better.

Comment: I can agree with this statement. Was out of work and hired by a company (well known globally) for a local office. Interview was literally 15 minutes over the phone and I was told they wanted to extend an offer. Got in and learned they basically cycled out contractors for in-house apps they'd been building over the last 5 years or so (and they absolutely should not have been). They didn't even have a code management system set up. I received a much better offer from another big company 6 weeks in and took it.